# Multicriteria Insert/Update

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a query that will insert new records to a table or update already existing records, but I'm getting stuck on the filtering and grouping for the criteria I want.

I have two tables: tbl_PartInfo, and dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.

I'm want to select from dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE based upon the combination of CUST_ORDER_ID, CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO, and REVISION_ID. Each customer order can have multiple lines, and each line can have multiple revision. I'm trying to select the unique combinations of each order and it's connected lines, but take the connected information for the row with the highest value in the revision column.

I want to insert/update from dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE the following columns:

```
CUST_ORDER_ID
PART_ID
USER_ORDER_QTY
UNIT_PRICE
```

I want to insert/update them into tbl_PartInfo as the following columns respectively:

```
JobID
DrawingNumber
Quantity
UnitPrice
```

So if I have the following rows in dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE (PART_ID omitted for example)

```
CUST_ORDER_ID   CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO   REVISION_ID   USER_ORDER_QTY   UNIT_PRICE
    SCabc                1                1              0             100
    SCabc                1                2              4             150
    SCabc                1                3              4             125
    SCabc                2                3              2             200
    SCxyz                1                1              0             0
    SCxyz                1                2              3             50
```

It would return

```
CUST_ORDER_ID   CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO   (REVISION_ID)   USER_ORDER_QTY   UNIT_PRICE
    SCabc                1                 3               4             125
    SCabc                2                 3               2             200
    SCxyz                1                 2               3             50
```

but with PART_ID included and without REVISION_ID

So far, my code is just for the inset portion as I was trying to get the correct records selected, but I keep getting duplicates of CUST_ORDER_ID and CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_PartInfo ( JobID, DrawingNumber, Quantity, UnitPrice, ProductFamily, ProductCategory )
SELECT dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID, dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.PART_ID, dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.USER_ORDER_QTY, dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.UNIT_PRICE, dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO, Max(dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.REVISION_ID) AS MaxOfREVISION_ID
FROM dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE, tbl_PartInfo
GROUP BY dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID, dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.PART_ID, dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.USER_ORDER_QTY, dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.UNIT_PRICE, dbo_CUST_BOOK_LINE.CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO;
```

This has been far more complicated that anything I've done so far, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry about the long column names, I didn't get to choose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and think I found a way to make it work, but I'm still testing it. Right now I'm using three queries, but it should be easily simplified into two when complete.

The first is an append query that takes the two columns I want to get distinct combo's from and selects them and using "group by," while also selecting max of the revision column. It appends them to another table that I'm using called tbl_TempDrop. This table is only being used right now to reduce the number of results before the next part.

The second is an update query that updates tbl_TempDrop to include all the other columns I wanted by setting the criteria equal to the three selected columns from the first query. This took an EXTREMELY long time to complete when I had 700,000 records to work with, hence the use of the tbl_TempDrop.

The third query is a basic append query that appends the rows of tbl_TempDrop to the end destination, tbl_PartInfo.

All that's left is to run all three in a row.

I didn't want to include the full details of any tables or queries yet until I ensure that it works as desired, and because some of the names are vague since I will be using this method for multiple query searches.

This website helped me a little to make sure I had the basic idea down. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/max_query2_2007.php

Let me know if you see any flaws with the ideology!